# When arrays go awry?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C# by solving mathematical problems.  For example, I'm working on finding the sum of factors of 3 or 5 in the first 1000 positive numbers.  I have the basic shell of the code laid out, but it isn't behaving how I'm expecting it to.

Right now, instead of getting a single output of 23, I am instead getting 1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9.  I imagine I messed up the truncate function somehow.  Its a bloody mess, but its the only way I can think of checking for factors.  Second, I think that the output is writing during the loop, instead of patiently waiting for the for() loop to finish.

```
using System;

namespace Problem1
{
    class Problem1
{
    public static void Main()
        {
            //create a 1000 number array
            int[] numberPool = new int[10];

            //use for loop to assign the first 1000 positive numbers to the array
            for (int i = 0; i < numberPool.Length; i++)
                {
                numberPool[i] = i + 1;
                }

            //check for factors of 3 or 5 using if/then statment
            foreach (int i in numberPool)
                if ((i / 3) == Math.Truncate((((decimal)(i / 3)))) || ((i / 5) == Math.Truncate(((decimal)(i / 5)))))
                    {
                    numberPool[i] = i;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    numberPool[i] = 0;
                    }

            //throw the 0s and factors together and get the sum!
            int sum = 0;

            for (int x = 0;x < numberPool.Length;x++)
            {
                sum = sum + numberPool[x];
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            Console.ReadLine();
            //uncomment above if running in vbs
        }
}
}
```

Comment: when I execute your code I get an output of 50. It is always a best practice to use brackets ({}) to define the scope of the loop

Comment: First you initialize the array with `numberPool[i] = i + 1;`, but later you do `numberPool[i] = i;`, which is decreasing the value by 1. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @RaineAndrews try to execute the same code what you have posted. the output would be wrong depending upon your logic, but its not 1,3,3,.. as you mentioned. It is a single value.

Comment: I didn't mean to decrease the value by one!  I was attempting to find an action that would cause no change in the value.  I didn't realize an if() statement with nothing in its brackets was an acceptable action!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreach loop has a few errors.

If you want to modify the array you are looping through use a `for` loop. Also, use modulus when checking remainders.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberPool.Length; i++)
    {
            if (numberPool[i] % 3 == 0 || numberPool[i] % 5 == 0)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                numberPool[i] = 0;
            }
    }
```

Modulus (%) will give the remainder when dividing two integers.

Another useful shortcut, `variable = variable + x` can be replaced with `variable += x`

Please note that there are more concise ways of doing this but since you are learning the language I will leave that for you to find.

Comment: is it really worth the milliseconds worth of difference to make it more efficient? (not talking about the entire program, just the algothrim you posted here)

Comment: What do you mean? What kailanjian suggested improves the readability of the code.

Comment: Usually smaller code is easier to read/debug and that is a good practice to get into. That is what I am trying to encourage.

Comment: @Andrew it was about his second comment, how he said "there are other more efficient ways of doing tihs but since you are learning the language", the only efficiency i see that can be done language wise is how the language does something

Comment: @Daemedeor I reworded it, is that better? :) Please don't take offense.

Comment: Dont you think foreach loop is faster than for loop? What is the problem if foreach is used in the above code

Comment: Why not use `if (!(numberPool[i] % 3 == 0 || numberPool[i] % 5 == 0))` That way you can leave out the else. Unless something should be done inside of the else loop.

Comment: wow, I need to look over the different operators again.  I totally forgot about modulus.  It makes the code so pretty!!!

Comment: @kailanjian its not about offence, i was actually a bit curious myself but didn't want to force you to give out the answer, so was asking using subtleties  :P

Comment: @Bauss, you are right, or you could use this instead: `if (numberPool[i] % 3 != 0 && numberPool[i] % 5 != 0)`. ;)

Answer (score 2):

@kailanjian gave some great advice for you but here is another way your initial logic can be simplified for understanding:

```
//the sum of factors
int sum = 0;

//the maximum number we will test for
int maxNum = 1000;

//iterate from 1 to our max number
for (int i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++)
{
    //the number is a factor of 3 or 5
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
}

//output our sum
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

You also stated:

> Second, I think that the output is writing during the loop, instead of patiently waiting for the for() loop to finish.

Your program logic will execute in the order that you list it and won't move on to the next given command until it is complete with the last. So your sum output will only be printed once it has completed our for loop iteration.

Comment: oh wow... I didn't even need an array... thanks for the pointer!